# Firebase Microsoft sign in OAuth throwing NSDictionary error

Tags: swift, firebase, oauth, firebase-authentication, microsoft-graph-api

'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM lowercaseString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600002e56880'

I'm trying to sign in a user with Microsoft in firebase but I keep getting the error above at runtime and I can't find out why. The error is given in app delegate when I run. Using breakpoints, I found out the error happens at
let provider = OAuthProvider(providerID: "microsoft.com").

```
let provider = OAuthProvider(providerID: "microsoft.com")
    provider.scopes = ["Users.ReadWrite", "Calendars.Read", "Calendars.ReadWrite"]
    provider.getCredentialWith(nil) { credential, error in
        if error != nil {
            // Handle error
            return
        }
        if credential != nil {
            FirebaseAuth.Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential!) { authResult, error in
                if error != nil {
                    // Handle error.
                }
                // User is signed in.
                // IdP data available in authResult.additionalUserInfo.profile.
                // OAuth access token can also be retrieved:
                // credential.accessToken
            }
        }
    }
```

#0  0x0000000105253faa in __exceptionPreprocess ()
#4  0x000000010525a7a8 in _CF_forwarding_prep_0 ()
#5  0x0000000101cf9c97 in +[FIRAuthWebUtils isCallbackSchemeRegisteredForCustomURLScheme:] at /MYPATH/MYFOLDER/Pods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth/Sources/Utilities/FIRAuthWebUtils.m:47
#6  0x0000000101d0aba8 in -[FIROAuthProvider initWithProviderID:auth:] at /MYPATH/MYFOLDER/Pods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth/Sources/AuthProvider/OAuth/FIROAuthProvider.m:228
#7  0x0000000101d09200 in +[FIROAuthProvider providerWithProviderID:] at /MYPATH/MYFOLDER/Pods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth/Sources/AuthProvider/OAuth/FIROAuthProvider.m:128
#8  0x0000000100c44585 in @nonobjc FIROAuthProvider.__allocating_init(providerID:) ()
#9  0x0000000100c4433e in ViewController.viewDidLoad() at /MYPATH/StackOverflowErrors/StackOverflowErrors/ViewController.swift:24
#10 0x0000000100c44afb in @objc ViewController.viewDidLoad() ()
#39 0x000000011b10539c in UIApplicationMain ()
#40 0x0000000100c4590b in main at /MYPATH/StackOverflowErrors/StackOverflowErrors/AppDelegate.swift:12
#41 0x0000000104d80bbd in start ()

Comment: What is the backtrace when the crash occurs?

Comment: Just added the backtrace to the bottom of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code, it looks like the URLScheme has a dictionary defined where a string is expected:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick. I had a NSDictionary instead of a String in my info.plist which was causing the error. Once I changed the NSDictionary to a String, the error was  resolved.